# How to erase canvas using the cursor

Tags: canvas, erase, responsive

I'd like to add a responsive canvas to a web page. This is just a black div and should be erasable with the cursor.

Div 1 (canvas) on top of div 2 (text). The cursor should erase div 1 and reveal div 2.

**Update**

I'm using this code but it's not working.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasTop");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var canvasOffset = $("#canvasTop").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var startX;
var startY;
var isDown = false;

function handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    isDown = true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDown = false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDown = false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (!isDown) {
        return;
    }
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    // Put your mousemove stuff here
    ctx.save();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    ctx.stroke();
    startX = mouseX;
    startY = mouseY;
}

$("#canvasTop").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});
```

```css
html, body {height:100%}
body {
  margin:0; padding:0;
}
#wrapper {
  position:relative; 
  margin:auto; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  background-color:#ffffff
}
#canvasTop {
  position:absolute; 
  top:0px; 
  left:0px; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
}
#text {
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  right:0; 
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto; 
  width:400px; 
  height:200px; 
  text-align:center; 
  top: 50%; 
  transform:translateY(-50%); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <canvas id="canvasTop" width=100% height=100%></canvas>
    <div id="text">
    <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Hope anyone can help!

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. Maybe check this ["scratch-off reveal"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503226/javascript-canvas-erasing-tool-doesnt-do-anything/21504265#21504265) example.

Comment: Thank you @markE ! This is exactly what I was looking for. However, I'd like to use this animation on top of a div with a text instead an image. How can I do that?

Comment: Same way...just have the div+text under a "scratch-off" canvas. Give a try coding it. :-)

Comment: I'm pretty new to Javascript and canvas. I'm not sure how to swap the image with a div which includes some text.

Comment: Use HTML to add your texted div. Use CSS `position:absolute` to put the canvas atop that div.

Comment: @markE I swapped the 'canvasBottom' with my texted div in HTML but I'm confused about what to do with Javascript. I removed the code for the image and the animation doesn't work anymore. I added a snippet to my question.

Comment: I've posted an answer with working code and explanations of the needed changes. Good luck with your project! :-)

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly! @markE

Comment: Hi, Is there a way to redraw this animation on window resize?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

These changes to your code should create your "scratch-off" effect:

- Move #text before #canvasTop
- Don't use CSS to change the canvas size. Doing so will distort the canvas.
- Set the canvas element's width & height to equal #wrapper's width & height.

**Here is refactored code with the changes annotated:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasTop");
// set the canvas element's width/height to cover #wrapper
var wrapper=document.getElementById('wrapper');
var wrapperStyle=window.getComputedStyle(wrapper,null);
canvas.width=parseInt(wrapperStyle.getPropertyValue("width"));
canvas.height=parseInt(wrapperStyle.getPropertyValue("height"));
//
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // set "erase" compositing once at start of app for better performance
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

var canvasOffset = $("#canvasTop").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;

var startX;
var startY;
var isDown = false;

function handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    startX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    startY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    isDown = true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDown = false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    isDown = false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (!isDown) {
        return;
    }
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    // Put your mousemove stuff here
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    ctx.stroke();
    startX = mouseX;
    startY = mouseY;
}

$("#canvasTop").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mouseup(function (e) {
    handleMouseUp(e);
});
$("#canvasTop").mouseout(function (e) {
    handleMouseOut(e);
});
```

```css
html, body {height:100%}
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#wrapper {
  position:relative; 
  margin:auto; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
#canvasTop {
  position:absolute; 
  top:0px; 
  left:0px; 
}
#text {
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  right:0; 
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto; 
  width:400px; 
  height:200px; 
  text-align:center; 
  top: 50%; 
  transform:translateY(-50%); 
}
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Drag the mouse over center to "scratch-off" reveal</h4>
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- move #text before #canvasTop -->
  <div id="text">
    <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    <p> Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvasTop" width=512 height=512></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will study every single line to understand how this work! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) { 
  document.getElementById('canvas').remove();
}, false);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mansim/krzpc1wd/

Comment: Hi @mansim , I mean something like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/fjTLF/) but with text inside a div instead an image.